# R package 'RcppArmadillo' error during installation

Tags: r, miniconda

I'm trying to install RcppArmadillo in my R environment.
I have created a Docker container starting from a Ubuntu:20.04 image and installing miniconda to manage the environment and install R.

When I install RcppArmadillo I have this error:

```
checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmp1znFrE/R.INSTALL3901267e6e22/RcppArmadillo':
configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
```

I have checked the `config.log` file to search the error, and I found this:

```
gcc version 9.4.0 (conda-forge 9.4.0-15) 
configure:1931: $? = 0
configure:1920: aarch64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++14 -V >&5
aarch64-conda-linux-gnu-c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-V'
aarch64-conda-linux-gnu-c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:1931: $? = 1
configure:1920: aarch64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++14 -qversion >&5
aarch64-conda-linux-gnu-c++: error: unrecognized command line option '-qversion'; did you mean '--version'?
aarch64-conda-linux-gnu-c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
configure:1931: $? = 1
configure:1951: checking whether the C++ compiler works
configure:1973: aarch64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++14 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O3 -pipe -isystem /root/miniconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/drone/src/build_artifacts/r-base-split_1630154255557/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.1.1 -fdebug-prefix-map=/root/miniconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix   conftest.cpp  >&5
/root/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-conda-linux-gnu/9.4.0/../../../../aarch64-conda-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /root/miniconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-conda-linux-gnu/9.4.0/libstdc++.so: undefined reference to `__cxa_thread_atexit_impl@GLIBC_2.18'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't understand if it's a problem of GCC (I have tried to uninstall and install again through apt-get but nothing changed), but seems really strange to me.
If I `echo $PATH` I get as result `/root/miniconda3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin`, but If I `find / -name gcc` I get:

```
/root/miniconda3/lib/R/library/BH/include/boost/mpl/aux_/preprocessed/gcc
/root/miniconda3/lib/gcc
/root/miniconda3/libexec/gcc
/root/miniconda3/libexec/gcc/aarch64-conda-linux-gnu/9.4.0/gcc
/root/miniconda3/share/licenses/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/gcc_impl_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h603953f_15/libexec/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/gcc_impl_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h603953f_15/libexec/gcc/aarch64-conda-linux-gnu/9.4.0/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/gcc_impl_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h603953f_15/share/licenses/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/gcc_impl_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h603953f_15/lib/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/libgcc-devel_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h85f5abf_15/lib/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/libstdcxx-devel_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h85f5abf_15/lib/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/gfortran_impl_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h54cdb55_15/libexec/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/gfortran_impl_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h54cdb55_15/lib/gcc
/root/miniconda3/pkgs/gxx_impl_linux-aarch64-9.4.0-h603953f_15/libexec/gcc
/usr/share/gcc
/usr/share/doc/gcc
/usr/share/doc/gcc-9-base/gcc
/usr/lib/gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

so maybe there are some mistakes in all these GCC instances.

Thanks for your help

Comment: how did you try to install RcppArmadillo?

Comment: Either downloading the .tar and executing it or launching install.packages('RcppArmadillo') from an R shell.

Comment: on this site, I generally see the advice to use `conda install ...` instead of `install.packages` when using a conda env (caveat, I have never used conda)